# spring xd job to create a hive table

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am trying to custom create a job for spring xd such that a hive table could be created.
I tried the following, but its not working. Any help ?

```
<hdp:configuration>
        fs.default.name=hdfs://sandbox:8020
    </hdp:configuration>
    <hdp:hive-server port="10000" auto-startup="true" properties-location="${xd.config.home}/hive-server.properties" configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration">
    </hdp:hive-server>
    <!-- basic Hive driver bean -->
    <bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/>
    <bean id="hive-ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"
       c:driver-ref="hive-driver" c:url="jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default"/>
   <!-- standard JdbcTemplate declaration -->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" c:data-source-ref="hive-ds"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <hdp:hive-runner id="hiveRunner" hive-client-factory-ref="hiveClientFactory" run-at-startup="true">
   <hdp:script>
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testHiveBatchTable; 
     CREATE TABLE testHiveBatchTable (key int, value string);
   </hdp:script>
</hdp:hive-runner>
<hdp:hive-client-factory host="localhost" port="10000" id="hiveClientFactory">

</hdp:hive-client-factory>
<hdp:hive-template />
    <batch:job id="job" restartable="true">

        <batch:step id="createhivetable">
            <hdp:hive-tasklet id="createhivetable-tasklet" hive-client-factory-ref="hiveClientFactory" >
        <hdp:script>
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testHiveBatchTable;
            CREATE TABLE testHiveBatchTable (key int, value string);
        </hdp:script>
    </hdp:hive-tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Comment: What was the error you're getting?

Comment: @MichaelMinella As in I don't see any exception or error, the job deployment is getting timed out.Here is xd log:INFO Deployer server.JobDeploymentListener - Deployment status for job 'testhivetable1': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=Deployment of module 'ModuleDeploymentKey{stream='testhivetable1', type=job, label='createhivetable'}' to container 'c01801f9-d221-4272-93ae-a7da1900d2c7' timed out after 30000 ms}

Comment: That issue has nothing to do with your job and is related to how you've configured your Spring XD cluster.  What bus are you using?  Single node or cluster?  Chances are, it was trying to deploy to a node that wasn't up.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I understand that but I don't see any problem in configuration. I am running a single node spring xd and Hortonworks Sandbox. Also to verify this I just wrote a sample java program based using spring hadoop I am able to create a table in Hive with the same Hive configuration. Would you like to see any configuration file or anything?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to connect hive server 2, if that is the case you have 2 problems here.

1. Your connector is wrong, it should be `jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default`
2. Hive tasklet actually [doesn't support connection to hive server 2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/61e279b6f5ed689a2e3fc800cd5a627e0d859589/spring-hadoop-hive/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/hive/HiveExecutor.java) because HiveExecutor is based on HiveTemplate the which one is using HiveClient (connector for hive server 1). In our case we implemented a class implementing the Tasklet interface to run our scripts through HiveServer 2.